# My database model (sucks) gives to mush headache, how to improve it?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, one-to-many

I have an app which is about sharing wardrobes between users. The idea is simple, members posts their cloths, others can comment or save them by pressing the like button.

I have three tables:

Products:

```
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| ID          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| NAME        | varchar(16) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| FBID        | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| TITLE       | text        | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| DESCRIPTION | text        | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| BRAND       | varchar(16) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| SIZE        | varchar(12) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| CATEGORY    | varchar(22) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| COLOR       | varchar(12) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| COND        | varchar(12) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| ORIGPRICE   | varchar(8)  | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
| SALEPRICE   | varchar(8)  | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
| IMAGES      | text        | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| TIMESTAMP   | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| SOLDSTATUS  | varchar(1)  | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
| VIEWS       | int(6)      | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
| RECOMMENDED | varchar(1)  | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Likes:

```
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| PRODID | varchar(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| FBID   | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comments:

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| ID        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| PRODID    | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| NAME      | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| FBID      | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| COMMENT   | text        | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| IMGPATH   | text        | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| TIMESTAMP | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

So far, (and I think I went wrong here), to display the products on the homepage along with the number of likes/comments I made subqueries using separate functions embedded into the query, like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FORM PRODUCTS"
if($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
             $jsonRow = array(

             'sqlId'            =>  $row['ID'],
             'name'             =>  $row['NAME'],
             'likecount'        =>  countLikes($row['ID'], $mysqli),
             'commentcount'     =>  countComments($row['ID'], $mysqli)
);
}
```

Now, after 10.000+ records, to improve performance I have tried:

1. To JOIN all three tables, but this way I can group / count things once for LIKES without the possibility of counting COMMENTS in the same time.
2. Or, to create new columns for: LIKESCOUNT inside the PRODUCTS table and update this each time a user likes a product by counting the product's appearances (PRODID) in the LIKES table.

Any other thoughts on how to make this right?
Thanks

Comment: what is FBID? also can't you change your screenshots to text please

Comment: FBID short for facebook id. I have tried to add text based details of the db but it wont format right, i try it again

Comment: does FBID stand for the same thing in the products table? if so why are product id and fbid both there in the likes tables

Comment: The FBID is the same everywhere. In the LIKES (and COMMENTS) table I basically save the list of LIKED products of each user and display it in their profile pages. To optimise things I use the same LIKES table for counting the total number for the main PRODUCTS page.

Comment: I can't add the textual scheme of the DB, rows just collapse in the editor, tried both code / quote blocks.

Comment: Done, I have managed to add the database scheme as text. Thanks for your help!

Comment: A good common way to solve this is to do your approach 2 AKA "counter cache". The only modification I'd do there is not re-count likes every time a new like is added, but increment when like is created and decrement when it is destroyed (if this is a thing in your app). How did it not work for you?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev this was exactly what I had in mind last night, it would be really simple, I just not know if it would be the best approach once I have a nice table filled with all the likes for each product

Comment: you can have an `intention lock`  to safeguard each time you want a summary row updated for its count. So, you have your detail. And an intention lock safely allows for the inc or dec of the summary count row.

Comment: @EdmondTamas: it is very good for displaying products (no need to query other tables) and only moderately complicates the code (the need for incrementing). It's a very common approach.

Comment: in the future don't use `DESCRIBE` for schema display. Rather, show the output from `show create table myTableName`

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, I will start to experiment with these approaches. :)

Comment: Lots of usefull comments. If I may add a couple more, you are using upper case letters for field names. The convention is to use lower case. Don't bother about changing these tables but when you create a new DB in future please keep that in mind.

Comment: the FB id can probably be placed into a table of it's own to reduce redundancy. . That way you will be having an integer in the products and likes table instead of a 32 byte string

Comment: @e4c5 grate idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To JOIN all three tables, but this way I can group / count things once for LIKES without the possibility of counting COMMENTS in the same time.

You can count LIKES and COMMENTS in one query. But you need to use subqueries (in order not to create a cross join between LIKES and COMMENTS).

```
select sub.*, count(l.PRODID) as likecount
from (
    select p.*, count(c.PRODID) as commentcount
    from products p
    left join comments c on c.PRODID = p.ID
    group by p.ID
) sub 
left join likes l on l.PRODID = sub.ID
group by sub.ID
```

You can also count the comments and likes in a subselect.

```
select p.*,
    (
        select count(*)
        from comments c
        where c.PRODID = p.ID
    ) as commentcount,
    (
        select count(*)
        from likes l
        where l.PRODID = p.ID
    ) as likecount
from products p
```

But i would probably run three queries

```
select * from products;

select PRODID, count(*) as commentcount from comments group by PRODID;

select PRODID, count(*) as likecount from likes group by PRODID;
```

and combine the results in PHP.

```
$products = array();

$query = "SELECT * FORM PRODUCTS";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $products[$row['ID']] = array(
        'sqlId'            =>  $row['ID'],
        'name'             =>  $row['NAME'],
        'likecount'        =>  0,
        'commentcount'     =>  0

    );
}

$query = "SELECT PRODID, COUNT(*) as commentcount FROM comments GROUP BY PRODID";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $products[$row['PRODID']]['commentcount'] = $row['commentcount'];
}

$query = "SELECT PRODID, COUNT(*) as likecount FROM likes GROUP BY PRODID";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $products[$row['PRODID']]['likecount'] = $row['likecount'];
}
```

Comment: Three possible solutions in one answer, too good to be true! Thanks man, I will experiment with all of them! :)

Comment: Thanks one more, it works like a charm. But could you help me understand 2 things? Is it possible to reference a table using only its first charater: "c.PRODID"? Or you initialise c here: "join **comments c** on c.PRODID"? And one more thing " sub.* " is a command, or it will be a result of one of the subqueries? I am a bit confused :P

Comment: You can give every table in the query an alias. `JOIN comments c` can also be written as `JOIN comments AS c`. `sub` is also a table alias for the subquery. So you can reference the columns from the subquery result by `sub.column1`.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info!